# Getting projects from the Internet

Tags: freelance-websites, attracting-clients

I'm an Android developer with about two years experience. I want to get Android projects from the Internet, but I don't know how to get clients.

How would I get clients online?

Answer (score 1):

Android forums would be your best bet. There are always people searching for android developers in these areas. I am also searching for one.